# Changing a value in a combination of different level nested dictionaries in python

Tags: python, nested

I have built a class of my inputs including different levels of nested dictionaries and I need to have a method in that class to change each of inputs but I do not know how I should modify that to work for each levels of nested dictionaries.

```
class model_inputs:

        def __init__(self):
                self.para_dict = {
                                 "analysis_years",
                                 "average_age":20, 
                                 "age_shape":10, 
                                 "overhead_line": 
                                                {'lifespan':10,'replcost':10000,'growth_rate':0.1}
                                 }

        def modify_parameter(self,parameter, percentage_change):
                original_param = self.parameter_dict[parameter]
                new_param=self.parameter_dict[parameter] = (1+percentage_change)*(original_param)
                return (new_param)
```

so I need to run that code for different parameters and change their value.

```
data=model_inputs()
data.modify_parameter(analysis_years,100)
```

it works for the above example but it does not work for nested dictionaries:

```
data=model_inputs()
data.modify_parameter("overhead_line"['lifespan'],100)
```

Comment: Please fix your syntax errors then give a worked example of what your output(s) should look like